# How can I get/apply change delta in Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying too keep two instances of an Ace editor in sync. So when the user types in one, the other is updated.

Looking at their docs I see that the [EditSession](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session) `change` event says that it returns a delta of the change, and the [Document](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=document) has an `applyDeltas` method.

So I have hooked into that change event, and when it is fired I call the other document.applyDeltas and pass it over, but it doesn't work.

I have been poking around their docs (and Google for an hour), but I am not seeing how to keep them in sync. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Nothing beats looking at src :)

The applyDeltas method on the document wants an array, AND you need to grab the data from the change event.

```
//on editor1.change
this.handleEditor1Changed = function (e) {
    var deltas = new Array();
    deltas[0] = e.data;
    this.editor2.getSession().getDocument().applyDeltas(deltas);
};
```

Comment: please do `applyDeltas([e.data]);`. `deltas = new Array();` looks like php:)

Answer (score 2):

If you looked at the source, you should have seen that `applyDeltas` just calls `applyDelta` in a loop for each element in the array.  Thus, you could simply do this:

```
editor1.on('change', function(delta) {
    editor2.session.doc.applyDelta(delta);
})
```

or, in more modern JavaScript

```
editor1.on('change', delta => editor2.session.doc.applyDelta(delta))
```

Comment: Great suggestion + FYI, there's a missing `)` on first snippet

Comment: @programmingisphun thanks, fixed.  i've been writing far too much python lately and my brace finger has gotten lazy.